# Could not find com.google.firebase:crash-plugin:1.1.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I wanted to try the firebase performance but I get this error when I add the classpath.

```
Error:Could not find com.google.firebase:crash-plugin:1.1.0.
    Searched in the following locations:
        file:/C:/Program Files/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/crash-plugin/1.1.0/crash-plugin-1.1.0.pom
        file:/C:/Program Files/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/crash-plugin/1.1.0/crash-plugin-1.1.0.jar
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/crash-plugin/1.1.0/crash-plugin-1.1.0.pom
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/crash-plugin/1.1.0/crash-plugin-1.1.0.jar
    Required by:
        project : > com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find the firebase:crash-plugin:1.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034999/cannot-find-the-firebasecrash-plugin1-1-0)

Comment: Yes it is a duplicated (but I was the first)

Comment: Yeeeaaah. But had to flag it the other way around since the answer was accepted there first (a requirement to tag duplicates is an accepted/upvoted answer). Nonetheless, all is well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that! The plugin was still in the approval queue on BinTray at launch time, but it is now live.

Comment: Should be there now, please try again!