# Cannot find the firebase:crash-plugin:1.1.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I have been trying to add the firebase performance dependency, I followed 
[Get Started with Firebase Performance Monitoring for Android
 guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android)

I have added in the top gradle file the     `classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0'` and the `jcenter()` repository.

But I am getting the following error that the `com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0` dependency cannot be found.

Also I have the latest version of the google play services(40) and the google repository(51) installed.

Here is my top `build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }


  }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Error:Could not find com.google.firebase:crash-plugin:1.1.0. Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/crash-plugin/1.1.0/crash-plugin-1.1.0.pom 
    file:/Applications/AndroidStudio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/crash-plugin/1.1.0/crash-plugin-1.1.0.jar 
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/crash-plugin/1.1.0/crash-plugin-1.1.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/crash-plugin/1.1.0/crash-plugin-1.1.0.jar Required by: project : > com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0
```

Comment: Try now, plugin should be live.

Comment: yep, it is live now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the plugin was not yet approved on bintray.

It has now been approved, so if you try again it should work!